# How paypal can protect customers data from there Business partners?

Tags: web-services, security, websphere, soa, ws-security

If business partner of paypal using paypal's web service in its website.If the web service is asking for username and password of its customer,how paypal can protect customers data from there Business partners?How soap transaction can take place between customers,paypal and its business patners?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are asking about 2 different things? But I'd like to try and answer them both.

---

QUESTION 1

If I am understanding you correctly your first question is asking how PayPal might provide protection to the customer from the "business partner," who I, like PayPal, more often call the "merchant."

You mention the username and password collected by the "business partner" so I will address that first. Usually the username and password are only secured by the site that they are collected on. Often a site will have a login and session that is separate from the login and session that is for PayPal. So, even if the site is using PayPal, the site probably does not use PayPal to secure the account credentials for the login to its own site.

If the site is using PayPal and the customer/user is prompted to log in their PayPal account to make a payment, then the credentials should only be sent to the PayPal site (you can look for paypal.com in the form action [view source]). Usually the customer will only be able to log into PayPal through a form on a page that is served by PayPal (paypal.com is in the url). I would would be suspicious of any page that is prompting the user to log into their PayPal account that did not have paypal.com in the domain of the url. Even eBay, who now is under the same ownership as PayPal, will have eBay users enter their PayPal account credentials on a page that is served through paypal.com.

There are several ways to implement payment processing with PayPal. It is common for merchants to implement PayPal payment processing in a way that has the customer enter their credit card information only to the PayPal servers. This is one of the ways that PayPal can protect the customer from the business partner / merchant. When the customer's credit card information is collected by PayPal, PayPal does not share the credit card information with the merchant. The merchant is only sent the details that are necessary to know the status of the payment/transaction.

PayPal also offers another type of protection to the customer. It is called "Purchase Protection" (formerly "Buyer Protection") and it is basically a mix of guarantees, policies, web applications, organization and more that is established to ensure that the buyer gets what they are paying the merchant for.

Additionally, I would like to add: Many merchants consider credit card information a liability. Some may collect it to provide the user with the ability to process future payments without reentry, but many simply do not store the credit card information to avoid the liability. You should never send your credit card information unencrypted. You can check that your credit card information will be sent encrypted by checking the form action of the form that is collecting your credit card information. Most browsers will let you know if your information is being posted across protocols that degrade in security, such as HTTPS (encrypted) to HTTP (plain text), so sometimes checking that the current url MIGHT be good enough (though there are still ways around this).

---

QUESTION 2

SOAP is a data exchange protocol that can be used to communicate from the merchant ("business partner") and PayPal. I do not believe it is common for there to be a SOAP "transaction" (as you stated) between the customer and the business partner (merchant), but from the merchant to PayPal, the PayPal SOAP API can be used. This method of data transfer is just as secure as other methods due to the fact that the communication must be encrypted to connect to PayPal's SOAP servers. See the details of the [PayPal SOAP API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture) or the [SOAP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) for more information.